# How to have one single command for terminal for run rails and db at once

Tags: ruby-on-rails, bash, terminal

I would like to know how on Iterm terminal on Apple I can have a bash command for run in one single shot all the commands I need to run my Rails projects. Like the rails server with port, PSQL and else.
I would like to understand that as will cause me to not waste time to run all the commands one by one.

Comment: See `help function`.

Answer (score 0):

It is quite simple to have custom aliases for certain terminal commands: open your `bash_profile` and add a line like this one:

```
alias pum='git pull upstream master && bundle && bundle exec rails db:migrate'
```

The above alias represents three commands in one, separated by `&&`. Replace `pum` with a name that you like and try to make your own!

This is a nice article to learn more about it: https://davidwalsh.name/alias-bash

Comment: What I will need is to run in one .sh command all the commands I need to write for start my dev env. Like the Rails app I need to run, the various DB I have and servers which need it for my projects. I saw my CTO writing .sh all start/stop but he never told me how he did that. I would like to see an example of it and understand how to do it.

Comment: The term you're looking for is "bash scripting basics" :-)